# Server bandwidth monitoring  program having Web interface

Tags: server, software-recommendation, interface, bandwidth

I am looking around for a simple program that will log how much bandwidth has been used by my server. This should preferably be presented in a web interface.

Information /summary/functionality I'm looking for is:

--Bandwidth statistics per day
--Log file of the last 6 months
--Login enabled access to view

Thanks in advanced

P.S -: Is there a desktop tool for windows that could log into the server and give real-time statistics that comes along with it would also be very useful.

**Edit**

I'll simply it I think. What is the smallest/simplest program that only logs bandwidth per day/month with just command interface?

**EDIT**

None seem to be what I want/am looking for.I'm now just looking for a simple program that logs bandwidth used by the whole system every day. preferably into exportable to html.

Comment: **Please** add your thoughts/opinions on answers as comments, not "EDITS" to the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your requirements i can suggest [**NTOP**](http://www.ntop.org/).
Search for **ntop** in Synaptic manger or Ubuntu Software centre.After installing you can view and configure it through **http://hostname:3000/**

ntop focuses on :-

**Traffic measurement**

**Traffic monitoring**,

**Network optimization and planning,**

**Detection of network security violations**

However, you may have to go through the [documentation](http://www.ntop.org/support/documentation/) and [Man Pages](http://www.ntop.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ntop-man.html) for optimum usage.

It suffice all your requirements.

P.S :- During web-page configuration it will ask for Username (which is **admin**) and password( Whatever you typed during installation) .

Comment: it is possible to turn off everything except for traffic measurement and traffic monitoring?

Comment: You will have to Configure it through preferences. But simply just don't view anything else if you just want Traffic measurement and monitoring. I would suggest you go through the Docs and Man pages , it will help you configure it better according to your needs.

Comment: there doc lacks alot or I'm looking at the wrong one. Is there a way to force all pages to require a login?

Comment: Well , try in Menu tab then Admin > Configure > Web Users. You can configure users and passwords here.

Comment: That doesn't restrict other people from accessing the 'open' pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use **iperf** to measure the bandwidth performance.It can measure the bandwidth of both your server as well as the client machine. Its an open source program which you can easily download. If you face any difficulties then you can use **Jperf** which has a graphical frontend to the iperf.
You can do various tweaks also based on the readings you get from these two as it allows to measure bandwidth and make changes to the network parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) to achieve this. It is a complete RRDTool based monitoring and graphing system.

There are cacti templates available online that will help you achieve your goal quite easily.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to tell but you will have to program such an application according to your needs. You can probably do it with PhpMyAdmin and then wrap it up to show graph and all the fancies that you want. Or if you want then you can use some of the wordpress' code because it contains those fancy stuff.